# mod rewrite in Expression Engine: removing directory in URL

Tags: url, mod-rewrite

I am working in expression engine CMS and I have some rewrite code to remove the `index.php` from the URL but on some of my URLs I want to remove the directory `/site/` before the file name.

Like I have `/site/pennsylvania_attorneys.html`

I want to remove the site part and just have it read `/pennsylvania_attorneys.html`

The current mod rewrite code I have now is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|css|themes|tools|admin|inc|js|cgi-bin|swf|themes|pennsylvania_attorneys_tpl\.html|license\.txt|attorney-tpl\.html|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /site/
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !^site/ site%{REQUEST_URI}
```

That will redirect any request of `/site/…` externally to just `/…` and reappend it internally if it’s missing on request.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could cut all this and simply do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ site/$0 [L,QSA]
```

And you don't have to "remove" the `index.php` from the URLs, you can simply never put it there. Shall work just fine.